# Bridge Number , Knot Theory

Tags: knot-theory, combinatorial-geometry, knot-invariants

I had been reading some knot theory lately and got to know about a whole classification of 2-bridge knots , does their exist any such extensive study over 3-bridge knots?

Comment: I looked around on ar$\chi$iv and only really found this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702867).  But its a starting place.

Answer (score 1):

There's a paper by Hilden, Montesinos, Tejada, Toro:
[this is the journal issue.](http://www.scm.org.co/aplicaciones/revista/revistas.php?modulo=Resultados&volumen=46&revista=Revista) It says it gives a way of identifying the links, but I don't think it goes much beyond that.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to go to the right place.

Comment: It seems to be hard to link to the second half of the issue, which contains the paper. The reference is **Revista Colombiana de Matemáticas  Vol 46 [2] (2012). 113-114**